# How to count row table in JPA Query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm new to Spring Boot. I have a mysql database, I use a query to count row in my table. But it's not work, it still return my original table data. Can you help me check my code.

Here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "act_id_membership", schema = "activiti", catalog = "")
@IdClass(ActIdMembershipEntityPK.class)
public class ActIdMembershipEntity {
    private String userId;
    private String groupId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID_")
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID_")
    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ActIdMembershipEntity that = (ActIdMembershipEntity) o;
        return Objects.equals(userId, that.userId) &&
                Objects.equals(groupId, that.groupId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, groupId);
    }
}
```

Here is my query:

```
@Repository
public interface MemershipRepository extends JpaRepository<ActIdMembershipEntity, String> {
    @Query ("select new com.example.activiti_restful.dtos.UserMembership(i.userId, count(i)) from ActIdMembershipEntity i where i.userId ='kermit'")
    UserMembership countMemberships(String userId);
}
```

**Updated code:**
My service class:

```
@Service
public class MembershipService {
@Autowired
private MemershipRepository repository;

public long count() {
    return repository.count();
}
```

My resource class:

```
@RestController
public class MembershipResource {
@Autowired
private MembershipService membershipService;

@GetMapping("/membership")
public long list() {return membershipService.count();}
}
```

My custom JSON Object class:

```
public class UserMembership {
    private String userId;

    private long numberOfusers;

    public UserMembership(String userId, long numberOfusers) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.numberOfusers = numberOfusers;
    }
}
```

MySQL Table:
[act_id_membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsdnn.png)

Comment: The query "Select count..." return a number not a List

Comment: I tried to fix my code with below answer, because this is my first time with spring so I'm still not solve it. I updated my code. Can you check it?

Comment: When I call my json link in Postman, it say: "message": "[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long",

Comment: If you want to count all rows from database, just use default function of CrudRepository, it means you do not need to write anything on MemershipRepository, just call "count()" function.

If you want to count row with specific condition, you can try it:
"select count(i) from ActIdMembershipEntity i where i.userId = 'kermit'")

Comment: ok I got it. Actually I want it return a json format like [{ name: kermit, value:6}]. Now it just return a number 6 only. How I can do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According [repositories documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) using `CrudRepository` provides a method called **count()** that is one of the [Superinterfaces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) which `JpaRepository` is implemented.

Based [CrudRepository documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) says:

> long count();   Returns the number of entities.

Then you should use `CrudRepository` method. In addition Remove Uppercase MembershipREPOSITORY, by [java code convention](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), you have to use by following way MembershipRepository.

```
 @Repository
 public interface MembershipRepository extends JpaRepository <ActIdMembershipEntity, String> {
 }
```

And use it in your Service:

```
 @Service
 public class MembershipService {

     @Autowired
     private MembershipRepository repo;

     public long count() {
         return repo.count();
     }
 }
```

**UPDATED**

Based on your requirement:
In Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MembershipResource {

    @Autowired
    private MembershipService membershipService;

    @GetMapping("/membership")
    public List<Object> list() { return membershipService.countMemberships();
    }
}
```

In Service:

```
@Service
public class MembershipService {

    @Autowired
    private MemershipRepository repository;

    public List<Object> countMemberships() {
        return repository.countMemberships();
    }
```

}

In Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MemershipRepository extends JpaRepository<ActIdMembershipEntity, String> {
    @Query ("select i.userId, count(i) from ActIdMembershipEntity i where i.userId ='kermit'")
    List<Object> countMemberships();
}
```

Comment: Sorry because I use Spring first time, I tried to fix my code like you say, but it still not work. I updated my code. Can you check it?

Comment: When I call my json link in Postman, it say: "message": "[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Long",

Comment: It is no problem. Remove line  @Query ("select i.userId, count(i) from ActIdMembershipEntity i where i.userId = 'kermit'")

Comment: and keep JpaRepository as well. that should fix your code.

Comment: wow! it worked. Thank you very much! But it's only return a number, if I want to write a query to show user id with a count number like my @Query, how I should do? Can you help me a little more.

Comment: I'm going to help you. But for that case you'd have to create a custom json object, for example public UserStatistic implements Serializable {  private long userId; private long count; //getters/setters } once this is created you should return it from your method with that @Query in Repository.

Comment: I created but there are a error in my log: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [UserMembership] -> this is my created class

Comment: @Tomato I update it, copy and paste it. it will work. I tested it

Comment: OK, please mark it as answer if this helped you. thank you.

Comment: sorry because annoy again but can you tell me how to add key into this json response? Ex: now it's return  [["kermit", 6]], i want it return [["name":"kermit", 6]]. I added @jsonproperty into my entity model class but it still have nothing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tomato could you please ask a new question? So  that I can answer you with more details. Copy and paste the link here and I'm going to help you. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139950/jsonproperty-ignored-in-spring-boot
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*> Actually I want it return a json format like [{ name: kermit, value:6}]. Now it just return a number 6 only. How I can do that? Thank you!

First, create a class to wrap your data:

```
public class UserMembership {

 private String userId;

 private long numberOfUsers;

 public UserMembership(String userId, long numberOfUsers) {
       this.userId = userId;
       this.numerOfUsers = numberOfUsers;     
 }
```

}

Then

```
@Repository 
public interface MembershipRepository extends JpaRepository <ActIdMembershipEntity, String> {
     @Query ("select new *****.UserMembership(i.userId, count(i)) from ActIdMembershipEntity i where i.userId = :userId")
     UserMembership countMemberships(String userId);
}
```

*****: your full package name

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks for your help!
But it's appear error in log: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate class [UserMembership]

Comment: select new *****.UserMembership(i.userId, ...

add your full package name at "****"

Comment: I'm really sorry for annoying but it still return only a number :(

Comment: Show me your code and value return after calling countMemberships

Comment: Thanks for your help! I updated all my code in this post and a image of my table. When I call in Postman, it only return a number 13 (actually it should be 6)

Comment: public class MembershipService {
@Autowired
private MemershipRepository repository;

public long count() {
    return repository.count();
}

Comment: while you still call function count() while new function is countMemberships()

Comment: I'm so sorry, as I say I just do Spring in the first time, I don't really understand the code, how I should fix, in the service class? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

to count the number of records return by the query with other fields without using group-by or aggregate function

```
@Repository
public interface MembershipRepository extends JpaRepository <ActIdMembershipEntity, String> {
@Query ("select new *****.UserMembership(i.userId, count(i) over()) from ActIdMembershipEntity i where i.userId = :userId")
 UserMembership countMemberships(String userId);
}
```